# Displaying information from a textbox into a listbox in a form C#

Tags: c#, string, forms, listbox

I have made the following form and I'm having problems displaying the number of members in the number of members listbox, here is a screenshot before pressing the button 'Add Artist'

[image]

and here is what happens when I press Add Artist, as you can see it uses the contents of Artist Name instead of Number of Artists

[image]

Here is my code for form1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Dictionary<String, Book> music = new Dictionary<String, Book>();

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((txtIsbn.Text != "") & (txtArtist.Text != "")) // if text artist name and number of artists is present
        {
            try { music.Add(txtArtist.Text, new Book(txtArtist.Text, txtIsbn.Text)); } //txtArtist
            catch { MessageBox.Show("Already Exist!!"); }
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Please fill in both Artist Name and Number of Members");

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        listBox3.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var pair in music)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(pair.Key);
            //listBox2.Items.Add(pair.Value.Onloan);
            listBox3.Items.Add(pair.Key);
        }
    }
```

and here is my code for the Artist class (called book because I edited a program I created before):

```
class Book
{
    private String mem; //mem = number of members
    private string artist;
   

    public Book(string mem, string artist)
    {
        this.mem = mem;
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public string MEM
    {
        get { return mem; }
        set { mem = value; }
    }

    public string Artist
    {
        get { return artist; }
        set { artist = value; }
    }
```

I've realised that it's adding the value of artist name from the 'Key' command : listBox3.Items.Add(pair.Key);

however I don't know what to change it to.. any help is appreciated thanks alot :)

Comment: yes wild i've tried that and it still didnt work, and lazy the listbox is supposed to display the number of people in the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure, but it seems like you want this inside the foreach loop:

```
listBox3.Items.Add(pair.Value.MEM);
```

Also, since the `mem` argument in your constructor is first, you probably want to swap what you are passing in so that it lines up:

```
new Book(txtIsbn.Text, txtArtist.Text)
```

This is assuming that `txtArtist.Text` contains the value you want for `Artist`, and `txtIsbn.Text` contains the value you want for `MEM`.

As a side note, it's worth your time to clean up the names, it will make it a lot easier to find problems later.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've just tried that and it didnt work.. definately going to change the names of my code though thanks for the suggestion - edit - just seen the edit trying now

Answer (score 1):

In your

```
    foreach (var pair in music)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(pair.Key);
        //listBox2.Items.Add(pair.Value.Onloan);
        Book b = pair.Value;
        listBox3.Items.Add(b.MEM);
    }
```

You don't add the contents of the MEM-property to the listbox.
But I don't see any place you are setting it, either.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
foreach (var pair in music)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(pair.Key);
            //listBox2.Items.Add(pair.Value.Onloan);
            listBox3.Items.Add(pair.Key);
        }
```

I think you want:

```
foreach (var pair in music)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(pair.Key);
            //listBox2.Items.Add(pair.Value.Onloan);
            listBox3.Items.Add(pair.Value.MEM );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your music dictionary containing book by artist name.
So the key is the name of the book, and the value is the book.
The right way to do it is :

```
foreach (var pair in music)
{
    var book = pair.Value;
    listBox1.Items.Add(book.Artist);
    listBox3.Items.Add(book.MEM);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching exceptions, simply check if book already added into dictionary. Also set books as data source for listbox, instead of adding them manually to items:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtIsbn.Text == "" || txtArtist.Text == "")
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please fill in both Artist Name and Number of Members");
       return;
    }

    Book book = new Book(txtArtist.Text, txtIsbn.Text);

    if (music.ContainsKey(book.Artist))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Already Exist!!");
        return;
    }

    music.Add(book.Artist, book);
    var books = music.Values.ToList();   

    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Artist"; // set it in designer
    listBox1.DataSource = books;
    listBox3.DisplayMember = "MEM"; // set it in designer
    listBox3.DataSource = books;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is the error message that I get when trying that though http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/4b/2c/4b2c33b782dacec8f1a5a192bab3df41.png , the closest to working i've got it is using listBox3.Items.Add(music.Count); however that displays this http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/77/0d/770d5c5fee5d9429fad24974603e2a78.png

Comment: @user2058186 hold on, I'll check this

Comment: @user2058186 sorry, just add `.ToList()` call (unfortunately ValueCollection do not implement IList interface)

Comment: @user2058186 just try code above. Manual inserting items one by one is not very good idea